# How to record log in Netty

Tags: testing, netty

I would like to implement a handler that records time from getting a request to sending a response.

Is there a handler already implemented in Netty that does similar task? (I can't find a way to do it with [LoggingHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/logging/LoggingHandler.html)...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not such a handler included. You will need to do it by your own.